# Forms not populating?

Tags: java, html, magento

I'm creating an application to login, and add items to carts. I'm almost done, problem is when loading up the product page, it doesn't load up the  to select product sizes. The framework I'm communicating with is Magento.

Any ideas? It loads up fine on my actual web browser. But it doesn't show up on my actual java program. I'm using jsoup to parse html page and use the getelements() features. I had it return the product page and it's missing the  selection.

Alittle more detail, I'm using httpclient, and http get to retrieve the product page data. All the cookies are configured, and headers are configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved, HttpClient is not a headless browser. It was not executing any of the javascript code. To remedy this situation, I suggest you find a headless browser package.